# AttributeError: 'DateTemplates' object has no attribute '_to_date'

Tags: python

The code posted [here](https://github.com/ceradon/cerabot-rewrite/blob/master/cerabot/tasks/date_templates.py), I tried to compile the program but everytime I do it goves me this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/ceradon/cerabot-rewrite/cerabot/tasks/date_templates.py", line 187, in 
    bot = DateTemplates()
  File "/home/ceradon/cerabot-rewrite/cerabot/tasks/date_templates.py", line 19, in __init__
    super(DateTemplates, self).__init__()
  File "cerabot/bot.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.setup()
  File "/home/ceradon/cerabot-rewrite/cerabot/tasks/date_templates.py", line 110, in setup
    self._load_templates()
  File "/home/ceradon/cerabot-rewrite/cerabot/tasks/date_templates.py", line 61, in _load_templates
    self._to_date.append(template.get(1).value.lower())
AttributeError: 'DateTemplates' object has no attribute '_to_date'
```

I'm lost, can anybody help in figuring this out?

Comment: the error occurs in the constructor of the 'Bot' class so you should provide that code too..

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/ceradon/cerabot-rewrite/blob/master/cerabot/bot.py) is the code to the 'Bot' class.

Comment: And neither class has a `_to_date` method, so you were expecting... what?

Comment: self._to_date is a list object. In the first few lines of DateTemplates.__init__().

Comment: You're right, this is very confusing as neither `start` nor `_load_templates` is even called in the `__init__` where it says the error is occurring.  Very odd.  You didn't happen to have renamed the `start` method to `setup`, did you?

Comment: Oh, *facepalm*, I updated the code on my server, but not on github. :P - I just updated the code.

Comment: Is it clear to you why it's happening now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `super(DateTemplates, self).__init__()` this runs `Bot.__init__` which calls `self.setup()` which runs `DateTemplates.setup()`, however this happens before you initialize `self._to_date` and so there is no list to append to yet.  Move the `super` call in `DateTemplates.__init__` to the end of the method and this should work.